# How to set a value of a text field if an instance variable is not null in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a new product form, and in this form I'll either get to it by going to products/new, or by passing in an instance variable on a button press to pre-populate the form using data from a 'feature' instance variable.

The code works for the most part, I can populate the form without errors, but I'm currently setting the value property of the text field to either nil, or the pre-populated values. If I then get any errors the form will reload, and set the values of any existing fields to nil, my text field code is:

```
<%= form_for @product, remote: true, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, 
          class: 'form-control', 
          value: @feature.nil? ? nil : @feature.primary_name %>
<% end %>
```

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to only set this value if the @feature 
variable has values, so instead of setting the value to nil, it doesn't touch the value at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set that value within the controller:

```
# in products_controller.rb
def new
  @feature # I assume @feature is assigned at this point
  @product = Product.new
  @product.name ||= @feature.try(:primary_name)
end

# and a plain view without special logic
<%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Another option might be to have a special method on `Product` that returns a new `Product` with the values set:

```
# in product.rb
def self.new_from_feature(feature)
  feature ? new(name: feature.primary_name) : new
end

# in products_controller.rb
def new
  @feature # I assume @feature is assigned at this point
  @product = Product.new_from_feature(@feature)
end

# and a plain view
<%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

As the question is changed this is the new answer.

In that case, you will have to do it manually but still you can avoid the condition by changing it to the following

```
<%= f.text_field :name, 
      class: 'form-control', 
      value: @feature.try(:primary_name) %>
```

If you are using ruby 2.3.0 and above you can also use the **Safe navigation operator**

```
@feature&.primary_name
```

---

**Old Answer**

You don't need to manually set the value if you are using form helpers properly.

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :primary_name, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Changing `:name` to `:primary_name` will take care of it

Make sure you are initializing the variable `@product` properly in `new` and `edit` actions

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
end

def edit
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

In case the `new` action is called the text field will be empty but, if edit action is called the value of `@product.primary_name` will appear in text field

Comment: Sorry about this, I wasn't clear enough in the question, I pass a 'feature' instance variable through to the products/new form, which is why I'm using a different value to the form's label - edited the question

Comment: Would the || or ||= operators be of use here?

Comment: Yes you can use `||` but anyway you will be getting `nil` so `try` is better